# Synchronizing android with the web

Tags: android

I was wondering if there are some commonly used techniques for synchronizing an app with a server? I have looked at the socket-framework and maybe some http? I am thinking for instance when making a game or a grocery list, any developers out there who want to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the most common method is to send client data via HTTP POST using SSL/TLS encryption.  The data can be sent in any format, but generally it is structured as a JSON or XML message.

The hardest part is that you need some form of authentication in order to identify the user and update/sync the correct information on the server database in a secure manner.  Have a look at [this article for some basic concepts](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/12/principles-for-standardized-rest-authentication.html).

In android, you can use the excellent [Google Gson library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert Java object to/from JSON objects.
Http communication can be performed via the [Android API methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html).